# CSS - Post checkmark in upper left corner of div

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have a `div` element that acts like a checkbox. When a user clicks it once, a checkbox will appear in the upper-left corner. If a user clicks the div again, the checkbox will disappear. Currently, I'm using the following CSS, which can be seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzeg86zx/).

```
.my-checkfield {
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: black;
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.my-checkfield-selected {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::before,
.my-checkfield-selected::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::before {
  border-width: 0;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::after {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-left-color: green;
  border-top-color: green;
}
```

As shown in the Fiddle, the triangle successfully toggles. However, I want to show a white checkmark in that triangle. How can I do that, preferably with CSS. I'm not sure where to go.

Thanks,

Comment: It is required that you post your markup here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/xzeg86zx/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By swapping the `::before`/`::after`, so the `::before` is used for the green corner, you can simply add `content: '\2713'` (`\2713` is the CSS code for a *checkmark*) to the `::after`

```js
function toggle(elem) {
  $(elem).toggleClass('my-checkfield-selected');
}
```

```css
.my-checkfield {
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: black;
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.my-checkfield-selected {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::before,
.my-checkfield-selected::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::after {
  content: '\2713';
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.my-checkfield-selected::before {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 12px;
  border-left-color: green;
  border-top-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-checkfield" onclick="toggle(this)">
  [hi]
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put anything in an element (or pseudo-element) that is only made of borders.

As such, you would need to, as a suggestion, use a square pseudo-element, with an image as a background and then have a *second* gradient background as the color.

```css
.my-checkfield {
  border: solid 1px black;
  color: black;
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.my-checkfield::before,
.my-checkfield::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: 
  url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/e/X/9/d/4/check-mark-white-md.png), 
  linear-gradient(135deg, green 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 70% auto, cover;
  background-position: auto, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-checkfield" ) ">
  [hi]
</div>
```